# File does not exist error in django,mod_wsgi and apache configuration

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application that I am trying to host using mod_wsgi and Apache webserver on Debain Linux.

The code works fine on my local machine and the Live server using the Django development webserver. I can successfully browse to 127.0.0.1:8000/index

When I try to run via Apache,
Here is the Error I receive (Apache error log)

```
[Fri Jul 04 10:46:17 2014] [error] [client ] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py/index
```

**I have read and tried all the combinations in the following articles**
-  webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial
-  docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/
-  library.linode.com/frameworks/django-apache-mod-wsgi/ubuntu-10.04-lucid
-  stackoverflow.com/questions/11380214/why-doesnt-apache-display-404-errors-with-django-and-mod-wsgi
-  blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

**Here is my Directory Structure**

```
.
 DataAnalysis
 ├── Application
 │   ├── admin.py
 │   ├── admin.pyc
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── __init__.pyc
 │   ├── models.py
 │   ├── models.pyc
 │   ├── tests.py
 │   ├── views.py
 │   └── views.pyc
 ├── DataAnalysisSite
 │    ├── Alt.pkl
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── __init__.pyc
 │   ├── settings.py
 │   ├── settings.pyc
 │   ├── urls.py
 │   ├── urls.pyc
 │   ├── Wann.pkl
 │   ├── wsgi.py
 │   └── wsgi.pyc
 ├── manage.py
 ├── templates
 │   └── search_form.html
 └── wsgi.py
```

**Here is my apache config file :**

```
<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    AddHandler  /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py .py
</Directory>

<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/mydomain.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/dmydomain.com-access.log" combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

**Here is my Wsgi.py file :**

```
import sys
import site
import os
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

# we add currently directory to path and change to it
pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(pwd)
sys.path = [pwd] + sys.path

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis')
      sys.path.insert(1,'/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite')

sys.path.append('/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis')
  sys.path.append('/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DataAnalysisSite.settings")

#from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#application = get_wsgi_application()

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**Here is my urls.py file:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from Application import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'form_test.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^index/$', views.index),
url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
url(r'^search/$', views.search),
)
```

I am using pycharm and views.py is in application folder along with unit.py,admin.py models.py and test.py.

**Here is my views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import os

import csv

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('welcome to python django')
```

Why can my wsgi file not find anything in views.py?

Is there any configuration error?
Any help is really appriciated!

Best

Comment: *What* file does not exist? What is the *exact* error? And why do you suddenly say at the end that it cannot find functions in views.py - what does that have to do with the error?

Comment: And why do you have that strange `AddHandler` line in your directory configuration?

Comment: What is the problem with AddHandler?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't make any sense at all to have one. You don't want Apache to invoke a handler for that file, you want it to be used as a wsgi application which is what WSGIScriptAlias is for. (But this is not the source of your problem, however.)

Comment: Where should I put views.py?

Comment: What does that question have to do with anything I have said?

Comment: Sori Daniel it was just an idea I had.

Comment: Here is the error I receive   `´[Fri Jul 04 10:46:17 2014] [error] [client] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py/index`

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what is going on: there is nothing to match the root URL, `/`. That should be obvious from your urls.py: you have patterns for "admin", "index", "search-form" and "search", but nothing for "".

However you should have diagnosed this before deploying. When you ran it on your local machine with the development server, what happened when you went to `localhost:8000/`? You would have seen exactly the same error, and you would not then have thought it had anything to do with your Apache configuration.

Comment: When running the Django development server using the command    $ python manage.py runserver   the django project can be successfully reached via the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/index   I have performed this on both my local machine and the live server.    The problem is I cannot get Apache to run. I need Apache since I want to connect my  domain 'mydomain.com' to this webproject and not have it only running internally.

Comment: Well I'm now completely confused about what actual error you're seeing. You need to post the *full* error message, either from the error screen you see or the log file.

Comment: This is the Apache error-log Error    
'[Fri Jul 04 10:46:17 2014] [error] [client ] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py/index`

Comment: I added my directory structure and the Apache Error I am receiving. I hope this makes the context of my problem a little clearer :-)

Comment: Have you tried taking out that AddHandler line, as I told you yesterday?

Comment: Yes we tried this and what we found is that it throws us into a loop of some sort. At least no httpresponse is recived from the webserver...not even a 500 or timeout. We have tried using Fiddler to debug te request response, but there is no response. :-|

Comment: Actually I would remove the whole Directory section there. You say you're following tutorials, but I don't believe any of them have anything like that anywhere.

Comment: I read at the following article [http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2013/04/26/from-php-to-python-getting-started-with-mod_wsgi/] that Addhandler  `..simply loads the wsgi module, and defines a folder (/var/www/wsgi), within which any file ending in .py will be executed by the wsgi module.`

Comment: What I cannot understand is why my wsgi file cannot find anything in views.py?  From my understanding the following line is wsgy.py links me to my Django applications  `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","DataAnalysisSite.settings")`  In the settings.py file is the reference  `ROOT_URLCONF = 'DataAnalysisSite.urls' `  which should load my urls.py

Comment: Thanks for the help and attention so far :-)

Comment: We removed the Directory directive from our Aapache config as you instructed but this returns the exact same error as before. `File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis/DataAnalysisSite/wsgi.py/index`

Comment: I don't know why you're reading random blogs from people who don't know what they're talking about, instead of following the actual Django or mod_wsgi documentation, both of which are admirably clear and comprehensive. Why for example have you commented out the get_wsgi_application lines and replaced them with older stuff? Anyway, the problem is not that WSGI cannot find the views, it is that Apache is not executing WSGI. That is what you need to debug.

Comment: If we state an incorrect url to our wsgi.py in our Apache config, we receive the error `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat:`  So I do believe that Apache is executing wsgi.py. We also previously had the problem that our sys.path didn't reference our Project directory. Once we added the line `sys.path.append('/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/DataAnalysis')` into the wsgi.py file that error stopped. Lastly we have found that incorrect settings in our wsgi.py can produce the error `mod_wsgi (pid=19931): Target WSGI script 'wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

Comment: I will see what I can get from this `https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques`

Comment: Make sure you are not putting project code under your DocumentRoot. You possibly have a AddHandler defined else in Apache configuration for mapping .py to a cgi-script. This can confuse things. Putting code under DocumentRoot directories is bad security practice because as any slight mistake in Apache configuration can leave your project source code, including passwords in settings.py downloadable by users of your site.